# Using polymorphism in serial communication stack c++

Tags: oop, polymorphism, embedded, message-queue, can-bus

I'm in the process of writing a custom higher-layer CAN serial communications protocol on top of mbed library for STM32 microcontrollers.

I have defined about 2 dozen messages that will be used in the protocol.  Some of the messages are segmented (i.e. 3 separate messages that may come in sequentially or not).

At the moment I have a big switch statement for processing incoming messages based on the message ID, and it looks something like this:

```
switch (msgID){
    case END_CHARGE_REPORT_1_MSG:
        return processEndChargeReportMsg(msgID);
    case END_CHARGE_REPORT_2_MSG:
        return processEndChargeReportMsg(msgID);
    case END_CHARGE_REPORT_3_MSG:
        return processEndChargeReportMsg(msgID);
    case END_CHARGE_REQUEST_MSG:
        return processEndChargeRequestMsg(msgID);

    case START_CHARGE_REPORT_1_MSG:
        return processStartChargeReportMsg(msgID);
    case START_CHARGE_REPORT_2_MSG:
        return processStartChargeReportMsg(msgID);
    case START_CHARGE_REPORT_3_MSG:
        return processStartChargeReportMsg(msgID);
```

Then in each process function I check if all messages in a segmented message group have been received, parse/format the message data, use that data as parameters in calls to functions corresponding to the received message.

I feel like there is a better/cleaner/faster way of doing this with polymorphism, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I want something like:

```
class myCANMessages{
    virtual process()
}

//Derived classes for each type of message group
class startChargeMessageGroup : public myCANMessages{
    CANMessage fullMsgGroup[3];
    process(){
          load CANMessage into fullMsgGroup
          if(allMessagesReceived)
                 parse(CANMessage)
                 take_action(decoded data from CANMessage)
    }
}

class endChargeMessageGroup : public myCANMessages{ ///etc...etc...
```

and then just keep processing incoming CANMessages (saving indexes to the relevant CAN Messages in buffer, parsing them when all have been received, calling corresponding functions using received data as parameter) with a structure like this:

```
myCANMessages *polymorphPointer

while(1){
 CANMessage = readCANMessage();

--> somehow assign this automagically to correct derivedObject type


polymorphPointer = &derivedObject;
polymorphPointer->process


}
```

....can't quite figure it out though... d'oh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a "CAN message" as abstract base class and then inherit this for each unique CAN identifier. But it sounds a bit overkill to me.

Usually I solve these situations with a look-up table, sorted after identifiers. Each item in the table contains a supported identifier and a function pointer. (Essentially, this is what polymorphism will boil down to anyway.)

Upon receiving a message, you binary search through the table to see if the identifier is supported. If so, then call the function.

Basically this pseudo-code:

```
CAN_msg msg = can_read();
const CAN_msg* supported = binary_search(table, msg.id);
if(supported) 
{
  supported->process();
}
```

It is also a good idea to always check if size (DLC) and RTR bit matches the expected for the given identifier.

Comment: I like this way of doing things (quick and dirty alternative to polymorphism).  How would one go about declaring/populating the lookup table?  I assume some kind of typedef or struct containing key/value pair where the key is my msgID int and the value is a void function pointer?

Comment: @macdonaldtomw Yes, a value pair struct. The function pointer should probably take a CAN message as parameter.